# Show that $\int_{(a,b)} (\int_{(a,x)}f d\mathcal{L}^1) gd\mathcal{L}^1=F(b)G(b)-\int_{(a,b)}f (\int_{(a,x)}gd\mathcal{L}^1) d\mathcal{L}^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a < b, f,g\in L_1([a,b])$ and for $x\in[a,b]$ let $F(x):=\int_{(a,x)}f d\mathcal{L}^1,\; G(x):=\int_{(a,x)}gd\mathcal{L}^1$.

Show that $F$ and $G$ are continuous and that    $\int_{(a,b)}Fgd\mathcal{L}^1=F(b)G(b)-\int_{(a,b)}fGd\mathcal{L}^1$.

---

I've been able to show the continuity of $F$ and $G$ using measure theoretic induction.  From that it follows that $\int_{(a,b)}Fgd\mathcal{L}^1$ and $\int_{(a,b)}fGd\mathcal{L}^1$ exist, since $F$ and $G$ are bounded on $[a,b]$. My problem is: How do I show the last equality?

Comment: Just integrate by parts. For the next time, a better notation would  be nice!

Comment: This is the familiar formula of integration by parts, and it's clearly valid for $f,g\in C([a,b])$ as then $F,G$ are differentiable with $F'=f$ and $G'=g$. Then I think you can use that $C([a,b])$ is dense in $L_1([a,b])$. Another method would be to verify the claim for simple step functions, and so on..